# How to add label from header field name in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, attribute-table, vbscript

I have some fields which contain numbers, when I added them as labels, it shows on the map as numbers. Is there any way to add header name of the field with the number?

[see this http://rghost.net/8LftSZcc8/image.png](http://rghost.net/8LftSZcc8/image.png)

Comment: Use expression for label 'officer no' & [oficer_no]

Comment: thank you @Alex Tereshenkov and  FelixIP, i used expression for label and it's working fine, but i want to add sbace between officer_no word and  numbers. <img src="http://rghost.net/8yJsfw6Xp/image.png" alt="see this">

Comment: thank you very much @Alex, it's working fine with me now, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can take the column name into the label directly. Your option is to either create a label typing the column name manually (`"PetrolLeft" + ": " + [PetrolLeft]`) or to use Python/Calculate Field tool to pre-calculate the column to values to include the column name (would be `Officer_no: 4, Officer_no: 3` etc).

To have a space between the label's parts, you would use:

```
"officer_no" + " " + [officer_no]
```

Another option is to use arcpy in the Label Expression window :

```
def FindLabel ( ): 
  fields = arcpy.ListFields(r"C:\Data\2015\OperationalData.gdb\Positions_Mercator","PetrolL‌​eft") 
  return fields[0].name
```